# Getting an existing resource in an OOP server API

Tags: object-oriented-design, node.js

### Background

I've designed and implemented a server app - a stateless REST API that mostly deals with customer CRUD operations.

As it is now the server is designed to use modules for each functionality instead of OOP concepts - although the 2 share some analogies AFAIK.

As an exercise, I'm trying to model some aspects in OOP.

### Creating a new object is straightforward.

Naturally I'd expect that creating a new Customer would simply be instantiating a new Object.

For example:

```js
// CREATE NEW
// User wants to Insert a new customer.
var customer = new Customer({ 
  name: "John Doe";
});

return "Saved Customer";
```

### What about getting an existing though?

What is considered a reasonable pattern if I instead want to get an existing that's already saved in DB?

For example is this a reasonable API?

```js
// GET EXISTING
// User wants to get existing customer from DB
var customer = new Customer().fromDB({ id: 1 });

return customer;
```

### Notes

- I'm not using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).
- Although probably irrelevant, the app is written on top of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not good. A customer has nothing to do with how its saved. You could save the customer in a sql db, or a flat file, it would not change anything else that customer is responsible for, correct? Therefore, the customer should not know anything about how it is saved.

Try this instead:

```
// GET EXISTING
// User wants to get existing customer from DB
var repo = new CustomerRepository("dbConnectionString");
var customer = repo.getCustomer({ id: 1 });
return customer;
```

Comment: Is this the Factory Pattern?

Comment: No, it is the repository pattern. The repository pattern is used load/save something to/from the DB, ect, that conceptually already exists.

The factory pattern is used to streamline object initialization. if we didnt want to keep on remembering the connection string, we would use the factory pattern to make the repository: var repo = CustomerRepoFactory.getCustomerRepo();

Comment: Sweet, thanks. Are there other, similar creational patterns that might be relevant to DB interactions?

Comment: yes, but nothing you need to worry about yet imo. You need to master the repository pattern first, it sounds easy, but most people mess it up. A repository should only ever insert entities into storage, update entities in storage, delete entities from storage, or retrieve entities from storage. A lot of people will make their repositories do things like, repo.upgradeCustomerStatus() which is wrong! The correct code is, customer.upgradeStatus(); repo.updateCustomer(customer);

Comment: That's the insight I'm looking for. Last question - any recommended reading resources about this pattern? Ideally would include guidelines like the last one you mentioned

Comment: A lot of people start reading about design patterns and go overboard, I once worked with someone who ALWAYS used the strategy pattern for literally everything. Even I go overboard sometimes.

You need to know the ups and downs of each pattern, and only apply it when you gain a benefit from it. With that said, hard to go wrong with the repository pattern :)

https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201633612/?tag=stackoverfl08-20

Answer (score 0):

Look into caching. The way this is generally done in java is to use AOP to intercept methods that create resources, and cache them (using ehcache, redis, memcached etc.) Using a relational database as a cache is slow. Also consider orm/oxm.

Comment: My question was more of a design concern rather than a speed concern

Comment: Hope your severs have a lot of memory Richard

Comment: The two things are interlinked. The way you make stateless applications 'performant' (I hate that word), is to use caching.
Generally caching mechanisms are designed for the purpose. Databases are not.
Look into memcached which is probably available in Nodejs

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer Memory is cheap

Comment: what if you have a hundred-thousand unique users? To just say, "always cache it in memory" without knowing the request and change frequencies is absurd.

Comment: Caching doesn't mean persisting. It means Caching.
Cache entries time out after a particular period, and the next time that resource is requested it is served from the back end, and cached again.
You 'tune' the cache to meet your requirements.
It obviously depends on your system, but each users can have 50 objects in memory, you can have a thousand concurrent users, and still not use more than a couple of gigabytes of memory for the cache.

Comment: Hmm, you should put that tuning thing in your answer, that's pretty important. Also, now that if you are caching, once you need a second server, you will also need a third server to act as the cache server if you want to avoid duplicate caching.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read up on it.
There are ways that you can distribute your cache, but it's unlikely you'll need to do that if you're using 'sticky sessions', which most small scale web applications do, if they cluster at all.
I do this for a living, for one of the largest companies in Europe.
We have services in place that serve a quarter of the UK every day, none of which would work without caching. I wish they would, it would save me a lot of work!

Comment: Yes, then I have the overhead of cache coordination. And if I don't have time to deal with that, I have go and pay you to help me... I am sure you are worth the pounds, but I'd rather not spend it unless I know I would benefit from the cache in the first place, which I would not if my data had a higher update frequency than request frequency.

Comment: Caching is a doddle. Actually far easier than using a database.
The user wants A,
Is it in cache 
   yes : return it
   No, get it, put it in cache, return it

I'm not sure if Node does Aspect Oriented Programming, but if it does, you simply 'intercept' all methods that generate content, and wrap it in the same piece of code that manages cache, it's transparent to the developer then. In fact you don't even need to use a bought cache, you can just use a concurrent hashmap that can time-out its elements.

Comment: I'm reiterating my comment - `"My question was more of a design concern rather than a speed concern"`. I also explicitly mention `fromDB()`. I haven't mentioned caching, or saving to memory whatsoever

Comment: Ok, last comment. That's fine. The general pattern for reducing server load in stateless web applications is to use caching.
That is a semi-permanent storage of already created objects, in memory, which obviates the need to re-create those objects.
In fact caching at all layers is usually used. So generally you might also use e-tags etc.
You can obviously cache data in a database, that would work, but there are better technologies for the job.